# Disable and enable link using PHP when admin click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem with my website project using PHP. How can I disable link (ex : register.php and login.php) when admin click button for disable link in admin panel, and enable that again when it clicked for the second time..

Anyone can help ? thanks

Comment: Can you share here what did you tried to achieve that?

Comment: You have to store in the database that it is `disabled` and based on that add `disabled` attribute to your `register` button. Also you need to modify the registration and login function to see if its disabled, then deny the access.

Comment: You need to maintain the status of all links in database and need to check when user visits that page...and then you can use jquery to disable that link.

Comment: I have 2 role user and admin, user can register (register.php) and login ( login.php),  if admin click button in admin page for disable register then register.php  will disable, and when clicked enable, register.php can access again..

Answer (score 0):

Store the admin selection in a database and set that property when the user loads that page.Assuming you are using raw PHP,just add disabled when admin is disabled and romove the disabled property when it is enabled

```
<a href="" <?php echo $status?'disabled':''>/>
```

Comment: Thak you for your answer, but can you give  the example, sorry im newbie..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deny access to those pages,then disabling the link is not enough,since the user can directly type the URL on the browser and access them.

I am assuming you are using raw PHP.

You need to check access status first at the beginning of `register.php` as below:

```
<?php
function accessIsAllowed() {
    $allowed = false;
    ......
    // Check admin status from database
    .....
    return $allowed;
}

if (!accessIsAllowed) {
    header('Location':'Your preferred URL'); //Redirect to your preferred URL eg access denied page
}
....
?>
```

And on the view:

```
<html>
.....
<a href="register.php"  <?php echo $allowed?'':'disabled';?>></a>
......
</html>
```

To disable the link based on admin preference